# crawling data from website and executing task on jira page

Tags: python, jira, ticket-system

so here's the problem:
- check a ticket tool for a specific incident (containing specific text)
- if specific text is found - open jira URL and create a sub-task
- close the sub-task
- switch to ticket tool and update status from a drop-down menu
- write a defined text as resolution note

how would this be realizable? which modules would be appropriate for this task?

thanks in advance

Comment: it should be possible to accomplish the task with selenium. i will try it out and see how that goes.

Answer (score 0):

I think you don't need to crawl the website. you can use the [python jira api](https://jira.readthedocs.io/en/master/)